# OpenCL reduction - 2D matrix to 1-D array

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu, reduction

I have a 2-D array of size MxN, where N is a power of 2 greater than or equal to 16 and M is an arbitrary integer which is not a power of 2. For example the size of array A could be 200x32.

I would like to reduce the array A to size 1x32 by doing a reduce (add) operation across the rows of the array. Most of the reductions I have come across reduce the array to a single value by adding successive elements using a Blelloch/Hillis scan algorithm. In my case though, the successive elements are unrelated and cannot be added. However, I need to add elements [1, 33, 65...] and elements [2,34,66..] and so on.

Since this is not a coalesced access, what would be be the best way to go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is coalesced:

```
WorkItem1 -> 1 + 33 + 65 + ...
WorkItem2 -> 2 + 34 + 66 + ...
WorkItem3 -> 3 + 35 + 67 + ...
...
```

As you can see all the memory operations in a group of threads are to contiguous memory locations.

Also for further optimization you can try doing vector operations, but my guess is that the compiler will already optimize it by itself.

Comment: I am not sure I understand it properly as I am learning this. Memory locations 1, 33, 65 are not contiguously laid out in the memory. How is this coalesced access?

Comment: Coalesced access is when every time "t" of the clock all the memory accesses are contiguous. Work item 1 does NOT run and finish, and then work item 2 starts, and so on. Instead, all run at the same time. And the memory required is t1->[1,32], t2->[33,64], ... so on